# PathFinding Algorithm not working

Tags: c++, path, coordinates, path-finding

I have a school project where we have to create a game on C++. We are divided into groups and I had to create the pathfinding for it. The program compiles (although it is very slow) and my algorithm does not work. It does not always find the shortest path. 
The game is the following: You have a labyrinth, a player and three enemies. The task is to make the enemies find their path to the player and they can move only one "character" every time the player moves.

```
#include "MapGeneration.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "EnemyClass.cpp" //use the enemy stuff to get the entity stuff
                          //in EntityClass see if the xPos and yPos are changing                            

using namespace std;

/* Variables */
int row; // rows
int col; // columns
const int enemnumb = 3;
const int playnumb = 1;
int playcount = 1;       // Counting how much players are left
int enemcount = 3;       // Counting how much enemies are left
int enemcordr[enemnumb]; // Enemy row number
int enemcordc[enemnumb]; // Enemy column number
int playcordr[playnumb]; // Player row number
int playcordc[playnumb]; // Player column number


/* Find enemies */
int findAllEnem(){
    bool found = false;
    while(!found){                                // If all enemies are found while loop stops
        for(row=0;row<MapRowSize;row++){          // Searches in rows
            for(col=0;col<MapColumnSize;col++){   // Searches in columns
                if(arrCurrentMap[row][col]=='e'){ // If it finds the letter 'e'
                    enemcordr[enemcount]=row;     // Save the row number
                    enemcordc[enemcount]=col;     // Save the column number
                    enemcount--;                  // Substracts 1 from the enemy count in order to show how much are left
                }
                if(enemcount==0){                 // If there are no left enemies
                    found=true;                   // All enemies will be found and will stop the while loop
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/* Find players */
int findPlayer(){
    bool found = false;
    while(!found){                                // If player is found
        for(row=0;row<MapRowSize;row++){          // Searches in rows
            for(col=0;col<MapColumnSize;col++){   // Searches in columns
                if(arrCurrentMap[row][col]=='p'){ // If it finds the letter 'e'
                    playcordr[playcount]=row;     // Save the row number
                    playcordc[playcount]=col;     // Save the column number
                    playcount--;                  // Substracts 1 from the enemy count in order to show how much are left
                }
                if(playcount==0){                 // If there are no left enemies
                    found=true;                   // All enemies will be found and will stop the while loop
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int enemMovement() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    bool makeMove = false; // to check if the enemy has already made a move
    bool legit = false;
    const int possible = 1500;
    int possmov = 1;
    int min[possible]; // minimum distance
    int countMove[possible][enemnumb]; // counts how many moves have been made with road
    int moveR[possible][enemnumb]; // gets virtual row without moving the enemy
    int moveC[possible][enemnumb]; // gets virtual column without moving the enemy
    int found[possible][enemnumb]; // if enemy found the player
    for (playcount = playnumb; playcount > 0; playcount--) { // for every player
      for (enemcount = enemnumb; enemcount > 0; enemcount--) { // the three enemies

        for (possmov = 0; possmov < possible; possmov++) { // possible directions
          moveR[possmov][enemcount] = enemcordr[enemcount];
          moveC[possmov][enemcount] = enemcordc[enemcount];
          while (legit != true) {
            int previous;
            int nRand = rand()%(4-0)+1; //4 possible directions
            if (nRand == 1) { //move right
              if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount]][moveC[possmov][enemcount] + 1] != '#') {
                  if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount]][moveC[possmov][enemcount] + 1] == 'p') {
                    found[possmov][enemcount]=countMove[possmov][enemcount];
                    legit=true;
                  }
                  moveC[possmov][enemcount]++;
                  countMove[possmov][enemcount]++;

                }
              }
              if (nRand == 2) // move  left
              {
                if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount]][moveC[possmov][enemcount] - 1] != '#') {
                  if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount]][moveC[possmov][enemcount] - 1] == 'p') {
                    found[possmov][enemcount]=countMove[possmov][enemcount];
                    legit=true;
                  }
                  moveC[possmov][enemcount]--;
                  countMove[possmov][enemcount]++;

                }
              }
              if (nRand == 3) // move up
              {
                if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount] - 1][moveC[possmov][enemcount]] != '#') {
                  if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount] - 1][moveC[possmov][enemcount]]== 'p') {
                    found[possmov][enemcount]=countMove[possmov][enemcount];
                    legit=true;
                  }
                  moveR[possmov][enemcount]--;
                  countMove[possmov][enemcount]++;
                }
              }
              if (nRand == 4) // move down
              {
                if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount] + 1][moveC[possmov][enemcount]] != '#') {
                  if (arrCurrentMap[moveR[possmov][enemcount] + 1][moveC[possmov][enemcount]]== 'p') {
                    found[possmov][enemcount]=countMove[possmov][enemcount];
                    legit=true;
                  }
                  moveR[possmov][enemcount]++;
                  countMove[possmov][enemcount]++;
                }
              }
            }
            legit=false; // returns the value of legit to false for next move road
          }
          min[enemcount]=possible;
          for(int i=0;i<=possible;i++){ // finds the shortest path
             if(found[i][enemcount]<min[enemcount] && found[i][enemcount] != 0){
                 min[enemcount]=found[i][enemcount];   
             }
          }
        }
      }
}


/* Main function */
int main (){

    GenerateLoadingMap(1); // Generate map
    findPlayer();          // Finds players
    findAllEnem();         // Find enemies
    enemMovement();        // enemy movement
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I wrote. Sometimes it finds the shortest path but not always. Also I would like for an advice on how to store the coordinates after every move.

Comment: I recommend posting to [codereview.se], if your program works and you want it reviewed for performance.

Comment: We aren't walking lightning-fast debuggers, and it's also not so pleasing to read that load of code you posted, so you should provide a [mcve] instead. You can also use the debugger your IDE provides. If your algorithm "sometimes works and sometimes doesn't", this means there's a flaw you can find by investigating on which input data it fails.

Comment: What pathfinding algorithm are you using? What topography? Can you isolate a specific problem with the code and post that instead?

Comment: Also some advice -- find the test case that doesn't work, and hard-code it into your program, in other words, stop using random numbers for now.  By using random data, it just makes your job much more difficult since your data is now a moving target.